# C# reads wrong registry data on 64-bit OS

Tags: c#, registry, 64-bit

I'm working on a 64-bit Windows and my applicaiton runs with elevated privileges. I have a problem with the following very simple piece of code:

```
myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run");
    if (myKey != null)
    {
    string[] HKLMvaluenames = myKey.GetValueNames();
    }
```

But for some reason HKLMvaluenames array is populated with values from the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Does you code have to run in 32-bit mode, due to an external/unmanaged dependency or something?

Comment: Is your application compiled as a 32bit app? Wow64 is the 32bit compatibility layer for 64bit windows OSs.

Comment: @Nick: I don't have to run in 32bit but I want my application to be able to work on 32 bit OSes as well (this is very important).

@Oded: Yes, I know what wow64 is. My application is compiled using VX2010 Express so I guess I can't even choose how it compiles. Can I check it somewhere?

Answer (score 17):

This is by design, 32-bit programs have a different view of the registry than 64-bit programs.  They are redirected to the HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node key when they try to read a value from the HKLM\Software hive.  If you build your C# program with Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform Target = Any CPU then it will run as a 64-bit program and won't get redirected.

32-bit programs can cancel the redirection but that's not easily done with the .NET RegistryKey class.  P/Invoking RegOpenKeyEx with the KEY_WOW64_64KEY option is required.  More info is available in this [Windows SDK article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28VS.85%29.aspx).

---

EDIT: this is now also available to .NET with the .NET 4 specific RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey() method.  Pass RegistryView.Registry64 to view the registry the way a 64-bit process would.

Answer (score 5):

While i was running into same issue or same focus of the reason for this issue, I found a solution.

Use this:

```
//To set the Base to the right path set RegistryView to DEFAULT, Registry64 or Registry32 regarding the path you need. If you want to go over the x64 root:

RegistryKey rk = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
        .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run");
```

Now it'll behave the way you want.

Have fun!