# Registry key null on 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, 64-bit, registry

This seemed quite a simple task. First I write registry key

```
string strHiveName = @"Software\AAAA";
RegistryKey key1_LM;
key1_LM = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(strHiveName);
key1_LM.SetValue("Val1", strHiveName);
key1_LM.Close();
```

and I find it here

> HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2753797750-1692135373-930909737-45181\Software\AAAA

when I want to read it with:

```
RegistryKey root_LM32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default);
RegistryKey foundProgramKey_LM32 = root_LM32.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\AAAA");

RegistryKey root_LM64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
RegistryKey foundProgramKey_LM64 = root_LM64.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\AAAA");
```

this since I want to make it run on both 32 and 64 bit machines so I expect that at least of the two registry keys are not null but that's not the case.

I have searched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843786/c-sharp-reads-wrong-registry-data-on-64-bit-os) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843786/c-sharp-reads-wrong-registry-data-on-64-bit-os) but none seems to help.

Comment: It could only end up in HKEY_USERS if you actually used Registry.CurrentUser.  Presumably you got lost in Registry.LocalMachine because you are probably trying it read it back with the wrong user account.

Comment: I don't want to have to give UAC full access. I am administrator how is it possible that I can't write and then read a value in the registry??? Additionally why in the provided links they say it's possible? thanx

Comment: The entire point of UAC is to give you full access *only* when needed.  Just click Yes at the elevation prompt and when you have an admin account then you'll always get it.  Pretty shoddy question btw.

Comment: I am try to understand that's why I'm asking. So I gave full uac access and it ended in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\AAAA which is fine to me.

Comment: But then I have put RegistryKey root_LM32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default);
    RegistryKey foundProgramKey_LM32 = root_LM32.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\" + strProgramName_Encrypted);

    RegistryKey root_LM64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
    RegistryKey foundProgramKey_LM64 = root_LM64.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\" + strProgramName_Encrypted); and I expected the 64bit key to be not null instead it's the 32bit. Can you tell me why?