# How to force setValue to Registry64

Tags: c#, 64-bit, setvalue

I'm working on an app that needs to write returned values from a POST to Registry64 and is instead using the WOW6432Node.

I've successfully handled the getValue function by using the following code:

```
using (var root = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
{
   //Code
}
```

However, I tried to do the same thing with setValue and this part is not working:

```
string[] portal = portalResponse.Split('|');

// Write each returned value to Registry64.
using (var root = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
{
    // Define destination subkeys
    RegistryKey writeKey1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\GMS", true);
    RegistryKey writeKey2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\GMS\VCT", true);

    // Write values to subkeys
    writeKey1.SetValue("Company Name", portal[0], RegistryValueKind.String);
    writeKey1.SetValue("Expiration Date", portal[1], RegistryValueKind.String);
    writeKey1.SetValue("Tech Company", portal[2], RegistryValueKind.String);
    writeKey1.SetValue("Tech's Name", portal[3], RegistryValueKind.String);
    writeKey2.SetValue("alerts", portal[4], RegistryValueKind.String);
}
```

I'm obviously unskilled at coding C# and would appreciate assistance with fixing this part of the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# reads wrong registry data on 64-bit OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843786/c-sharp-reads-wrong-registry-data-on-64-bit-os)

Comment: I handled the read and tried to use the same approach for the write but it's not working.

using (var root = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
{